# How can I force a redownload of the entire blockchain on the mist wallet?

Tags: blockchain, mist, wallets

I'm having an invalid date issue on mist. (https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/525)

I'd like to just try to redownload the blockchain again.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your OS, go to one of

- Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
- Linux: ~/.ethereum
- Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum

then delete the `chaindata` folder and restart Mist.

**Make sure you don't delete the `keystore` folder**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this `chaindata` directory has been moved under another parent directory called `geth`:

MacOS: `~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata`

Additional Information:
If you look under the Ethereum folder (I ran `ls` below), you'll see something like:

`$ ls
geth  history  keystore  rinkeby  testnet`

If you want to force a redownload of the for the Ropsten test network for example, you can just delete:
`~/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata` on MacOS.